# Command works from command line but not from shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am not much familiar with shell script. I want to modify a script but it's giving me error ***"No such file or directory"*** after I change it.

But that command works over the command prompt.

Here is the line which causes problem. (Even not sure how below command spawns a process.)

```
_T_COMMAND_=1 "valgrind ---tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes command"
```

same thing works if I run command as

```
$valgrind ---tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes command
```

Any idea?

Comment: To have a command executed, you need to do `var=$(command)`. Hence, you need something like `_T_COMMAND_=$(valgrind ---tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes command)`

Comment: but, it is working with _T_COMMAND_=1 "command". which I had modified to _T_COMMAND_=1 "valgrind ---tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes command"

Comment: Gave up script change... Fix the issue with cpp code change with adding valgrind to specific child process !!!

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the command in double quotes.

```
_T_COMMAND_=1 valgrind ---tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes command
```

The general syntax is simply

```
[var=value ...] cmd [args]
```

which will set the environment variable `var` to `value` for the duration of `cmd`.  You can set several variables in this way.

Alternatively, set the variable and `export` it; then it will remain set for the remainder of the current shell's lifetime, and be exposed to subprocesses (that's what the `export` does).

```
_T_COMMAND_=1
export _T_COMMAND_
valgrind ---tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes command
```

Similarly, `valgrind` processes its options, then runs the specified `command` (with any options) as a subprocess.

A single command in double quotes is harmless, because the shell will strip the quotes before the kernel sees the argument.  A string with spaces in double quotes will be preserved as a single argument, while without quotes, it becomes multiple arguments.  Behold:

```
bash$ perl -le 'print "<<$_>>" for @ARGV' "foo bar" baz quux
<<foo bar>>
<<baz>>
<<quux>>
```

or just as well, add harmless but no doubt rather confusing double quotes around everything which isn't already quoted:

```
bash$ "perl" "-le" 'print "<<$_>>" for @ARGV' "yowza"
<<yowza>>
```

The shell parses this into

```
<<perl>>
<<-le>>
<<print "<<$_>>" for @ARGV>>
<<yowza>>
```

and removes the (outer) quotes in the process.